# looping through a session array

Tags: php

Hello i got a question, i have a session array called 'addToCart', in there are multiple arrays with various id's, i would like to loop through these arrays with a foreach regardless of what the id name is. Does anyone know how i would approach this?

Comment: It could probably be helpful if you posted the output from `print_r($_SESSION['addToCart']);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the following construction satisfy your needs?

```
foreach ($addToChart as $key=>$value){
  // do anything you want with $key and $value
}
```

If you need to check "sub-arrays", you can check $value with is_array() function and add one more foreach loop inside.